# Windows Python 3.6.4: Can't find IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed the newest version of python (3.6.4) and I just had it upgrade from python 3.6.2 but now I can't find IDLE.
Please help I really need to get my work done.

Comment: What platform are you on? (I'm having this problem as well)

Comment: I'm on Windows. I actually think I found it.

Comment: Go into the Python 3.6.4 folder and search IDLE.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to include "windows" tag and put your solution as an answer if it solves the problem : )

Comment: There's a folder called idlelib. Go into that and there is a file called idle.bat this is it I believe.

Comment: Did you get yours?

Comment: That should be it.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Thanks,

Comment: Cool! I finally did something!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into the Python 3.6.4 folder, search for IDLE, then a folder called idlelib will appear. Go into that and there is a file called idle.bat; this is it.

Comment: It's there alright, thanks for that.  
Gosh, why did they have to make it so obscure? Just put it in the intallation root folder.

Comment: Any way to add IDLE to my list of programs to open the file (in windows)?